# Symfony Select2 on EntityType: do not load all choices in HTML

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2, symfony

I have the following form. Both for `device` and `parts`, I want to suppress Symfony loading all the choices into the HTML as I am already using a Select2 hook to load the choices through Ajax, and adding choices adds a lot of bloat (there are over 4000 parts).

What should I do? I tried adding `'choices' => array()`, which indeed serves an empty list, bu results in an invalid form, as this means that there are no valid available choices.

```
<?php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('device', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Toestel', 'class' => 'AppBundle:Device', 'choice_label' => function($device) {
              return $device->getBrand()->getName().' '.$device->getName();
        }))
        ->add('parts', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Onderdelen', 'class' => 'AppBundle:Part', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'multiple' => true))
        ->getForm();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a querybuilder instead. This will show you a good example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

I think you can figure it out from the above link...

OK EDIT #2 according to your comments:

Try using the 'choices' option shown below:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('device', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Toestel',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Device',
                'choices' => $device->getBrand()->getName().' '.$device->getName(),
        }))
        ->add('parts', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Onderdelen',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Part',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true))
        ->getForm();
}
```

Not certain that this will work for you though, but it might.
The variable `$device` needs be passed in as the form options, or somewhere else as a variable that represents the object AppBundle:Device.

Try this and see if it works for you!

Edit #3:
Based on your comments. I understand what you mean by loading with AJAX. What are you using? Maybe 'onload' for the body? You don't show the code.

However, maybe the best solution then is a ChoiceType with an empty array. If the empty array doesn't work, try putting something in it.

Try these suggestions. I only did it for the 'device' drop down list, since I'm not sure which one(s) you need it for:

Null array:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('device', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Toestel',
                'choices' => array(
                            //null
                     ),
        }))
        ->add('parts', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Onderdelen',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Part',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true))
        ->getForm();
}
```

Array with garbage in it:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('device', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Toestel',
                'choices' => array(
                            'Something' => true,
                     ),
        }))
        ->add('parts', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Onderdelen',
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Part',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true))
        ->getForm();
}
```

Try them!

Comment: Thanks, Alvin, but I'm not sure what is happening in the example; it's relatively poorly documented. How do I make sure nothing at all is passed as choices, while allowing any value to be a valid choice?

Comment: I edited my post based on your comments. Take a look bluppfisk.

Comment: Hm not that's not exactly what I want. I want there to be no choices at all. If you give no value for `choices`, it will automatically load all the device names into the choices option. If you do, it will also load the * of every choice. Then it will in my case put 4000 <option> tags into the HTML.

What I need is for Symfony _not_ to load any choices at all, I'm already loading them with an AJAX call.

Comment: I made a 3rd edit bluppfisk, this time with ChoiceType. See if that works. If it doesn't work, I'm wondering if there is another problem. I think something like one of these should work. Maybe the next step is post some code that you might suspect. Like maybe the AJAX code or Javascript???

Comment: Hi, unfortunately ChoiceType won't work either because the data expected on 'device' and 'parts' is of the Device and Parts type. So a mere ChoiceType won't do.

The Ajax doesn't actually matter, it's just a Select2 JS that loads the parts as the user starts to type rather than everything upfront.

Comment: Snap, I thought I found a way. I managed to create a ChoiceLoaderInterface implementation called Nullloader (which simply returns an empty type). It's without a doubt a dirty hack and should IMHO be a lot simpler to do, but it gave a proper empty choices list.

But it won't take the string data I'm loading from AJAX as valid input. If I have to convert that data on input, I may as well just use an unmapped ChoiceType...

Comment: Hi bluppfisk. I tried to help the best I could. I don't think I can suggest anything further. I normally check all Symffony3 posts to see if I can provide some useful feedback. If you think anything has been useful or helpful, please upvote so users will know the information is on the right track. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution of sorts. It's not excellent but it beats loading over 4000 HTML option tags.

It was harder than I think it should've been, but with the alsatian/form-bundle, it works fine. Read [More info on alsatian/form-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178424/custom-entity-type-working-with-ajax-and-select2-4-0-0) from the coder himself.

You're going to want to tweak it a bit though, especially if you're not using MongoDB. E.g. in the bundle's `services.yml` I had to comment out:

`- [setDocumentManager,["@doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager"]]`

And in order to even install it, you have to set `minimum-stability` in composer.json to `dev` - and in order not to break everything else, you should also set `prefer-stable` to `true`.

in order for it to work on my MySQL setup. Otherwise it's also not very good at setting options for the Select2 element. I was able to tweak `AbstractRoutableType.php` a bit so it could also take different request methods, but there's no advanced data parsing as you would need JavaScript for that (I don't think HTML `data-` properties can convey functions).

So in the end, I still have all those options configured in my Twig file, between `<script>` tags.